# Saved image cannot be opened using eligrey's filesaver

Tags: reactjs, filesaver.js

I am using `react` to create front-end.

I have a download button which will trigger an action.

The action will use `axios.post` to call the server which will return a file.

The `axios.response` is something like this

```
resopnse.data: 'binary data of image file'
response.headers: {
  cache-control:"public, max-age=0"
  content-disposition:"attachment; filename="test.jpg""
  content-type:"image/jpeg"
  last-modified:"Mon, 22 Jan 2018 18:49:27 GMT"
}
```

`response.data` is tested using `postman` which converts the response to the correct image.

Now I am going to use [eligrey's filesaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save it.

This is what I have.

```
    let fileName = getFileNameFromContentDisposition(response.headers);
    let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.headers["content-type"]});
    fileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName, true);
```

The code is tested using `Chrome`. The code will create a `jpeg` file, but it cannot be opened.

I played around with solutions provided for similar questions in GitHub and this website. But none of it is working.

I believe I am missing trivial setting to make this work.

Comment: After testing with a different library (http://danml.com/download.html), I believe the problem is how the blob is saved. `axios.post` returns a `string` value of the file. Writing the data directly to a new file is not correct. What could be the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the library.

`axios` is the cause. The response from `axios` is already converted to `json`. So the `binary data` lost some information.

Even when the `blob string` from`axios`'s reply is converted back to `blob`. It is a corrupted `blob`.

The workaround is to use `fetch`, and convert the response to `response.blob()`.